# How to give write permission to a team for a repository using Octokit/GitHub API?

Tags: github, github-api, octokit-js

I'm using JavaScript and Octokit to dynamically create repositories in an organization and set a series of options.

Everything works, except adding `write` permissions to a team for the repository created.

Just to be clear, by `write` permission I mean the ones that can be set through the repository settings:

`Settings > Collaborators and teams > Manage Acccess > Role: Write`

What I've been trying to use so far, was the `octokit.rest.teams.addOrUpdateRepoPermissionsInOrg` function in Octokit, documented [here](https://octokit.github.io/rest.js/v18#teams-add-or-update-repo-permissions-in-org), like this:

```
octokit.rest.teams.addOrUpdateRepoPermissionsInOrg({
  org: "org-name",
  team_slug: "team-name",
  owner: "owner-name",
  repo: "repo-name",
  permission: "write",
}
```

When doing this, I receive a `Validation Failed` error.

Checking the relative documentation on the [GitHub API docs](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/teams/teams#add-or-update-team-repository-permissions), it effectively seems that the valid values for `permission` are: `pull`, `push`, `admin`, `maintain`, `triage`

So I guess that I'm simply using the wrong function.

But what's the correct one to change that kind of permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to make it work: apparently, the `push` permission in the API corresponds to the `write` permission in the GitHub web interface.

FYI: this seems like a discrepancy, so I opened an [issue](https://github.com/github/rest-api-description/issues/1378).